# lsof displays restored file as deleted

Tags: inode, lsof

If I create a file named */home/martin/testfile.txt*, open this file with *less* utility, delete */home/martin/testfile.txt* file and restore it from file descriptor directory under the */proc/31148*, where 31148 is the PID of the *less* utility, then `lsof | grep testfile.txt` still shows *testfile.txt* as deleted:

```
martin@potato:~$ echo test > testfile.txt
martin@potato:~$ ls -li ~/testfile.txt
247 -rw-r--r-- 1 martin martin 5 24. veebr 05:02 /home/martin/testfile.txt
martin@potato:~$ xterm -hold -e "less /home/martin/testfile.txt" &
[1] 31145
martin@potato:~$ lsof | grep testfile.txt
less      31148      martin    4r      REG                8,9        5        247 /home/martin/testfile.txt
martin@potato:~$ rm -v /home/martin/testfile.txt
removed `/home/martin/testfile.txt'
martin@potato:~$ lsof | grep testfile.txt
less      31148      martin    4r      REG                8,9        5        247 /home/martin/testfile.txt (deleted)
martin@potato:~$ cp -v /proc/31148/fd/4 /home/martin/testfile.txt
`/proc/31148/fd/4' -> `/home/martin/testfile.txt'
martin@potato:~$ ls -li ~/testfile.txt
263 -rw-r--r-- 1 martin martin 5 24. veebr 05:04 /home/martin/testfile.txt
martin@potato:~$ cat ~/testfile.txt
test
martin@potato:~$ lsof | grep testfile.txt
less      31148      martin    4r      REG                8,9        5        247 /home/martin/testfile.txt (deleted)
martin@potato:~$
```

Is this because *testfile.txt* got a new inode number? Or is there some other reason why *lsof* displays restored file as deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are two different files. By copying (`cp`) the file from /proc, you are simply creating a new file with a new inode. You can test it with the `stat`command -

[root@server2 tmp]# `stat testfile.txt`
  File: test.txt
  Size: 9           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 803h/2051d  `Inode: 3684616`     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-02-23 19:01:14.000679872 -0800
Modify: 2013-02-23 19:01:14.000679872 -0800
Change: 2013-02-23 19:01:14.000679872 -0800

[root@server2 tmp]# `stat testfile.txt`
  File: test.txt
  Size: 9           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 803h/2051d  `Inode: 3684617`     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-02-23 19:02:46.422854012 -0800
Modify: 2013-02-23 19:02:44.507799688 -0800
Change: 2013-02-23 19:02:44.507799688 -0800

Comment: Try using `mv` and observing the behaviour. mv is useful if you want/need to preserve everything about the file including the inode and excepting the name. You can then `cp` the `mv`'ed file back into place with the old name.

Comment: @davey But it isn't possible to move a file under _/proc_ directory, is it? For example: if I execute `martin@potato:~$ mv -f /proc/3688/fd/4 /home/martin/testfile.txt`, I receive `mv: cannot remove `/proc/3688/fd/4': Permission denied` error.